# Using webpack watch and npm-watch together

Tags: express, npm, webpack

My app uses Webpack and an Express server. Will I create problems if I run `webpack --watch` in one terminal tab, and `npm run watch` in another?

Is there a better way to auto-build after files change, and also refresh the server?

Answer (score 1):

I guess it won't create any problem and if you make any changes in your component, webpack will automatically compile the changes and you need not refresh the server. Use this in your `package.json`

```
  "scripts": {
        "start": "webpack-dev-server --hot"
    }
```

Install by using `npm install webpack-dev-server`

Hope it helps!